# HTML link in search is not working

Tags: html, hyperlink

I have a simple code for searching, but I have mistake there. I think it will be little mistake, but I can't find it for 30 minutes. [Here is live demo](http://xrecenze.cz/search.php?q=Neco). As you can see, link in the first box is not working. Why?

//Code from live demo

```
<div style="font-size: 28px; position: relative; top: 30px;">Recenze:</div>
<section class="posledni">
<article>
<img src="img/recenze_img.png" class="nahled" alt="recenze">
<p><h3><a href="http://xrecenze.cz/9-recenze-neco">Neco</a></h3></p><p>Napsal: <b>testovaci1</b> dne <b>11.11.2014</b></p>
<div class="hodnoceni">
<p>Hodnocení</p>
<div class="hvezdicky">
<img src="img/star_a.png" alt="hodnoceni">
<img src="img/star_a.png" alt="hodnoceni">
<img src="img/star.png" alt="hodnoceni">
<img src="img/star.png" alt="hodnoceni">
<img src="img/star.png" alt="hodnoceni">
</div>
</div>
</article>
</section>
```

Thank you very much.

Comment: Please provide relevant code in your question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

without having more of your code, than the linked example it looks like your a DIV is overlapping your sections. Try adding this CSS:

```
section.posledni { 
  position: relative;
  z-index: 900; 
}
```

Comment: That's it, thank you! I can't vote up because of reputation, I'm sorry.

Comment: In three minutes. I'll do it. :)